# For a poset with ground set P, isn't every set containing a single element of $X$ a chain of $P$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

For example, consider this partially ordered set from my textbook solely through its Hasse diagram:

[image]

My textbook says that one of the chains of the poset $P$ above is ${1}$. This makes sense. Explicitly using definitions of partial orders and their chains, here is the logic:

Posets are transitive, therefore $1$ is related to itself through the partial order relation, therefore $1$ is comparable to itself, therefore every pair of distinct elements in $\{1\}$ are comparable to each other, therefore $\{1\}$ is a chain of $P$

But apparently $\{3\}$ is not a chain, but instead is an antichain of $P$. Why is this? I could follow the same logic as I did for $\{1\}$ to conclude that $\{3\}$ should also be a chain...

Comment: $\{3\}$ is both, just like $\{1\}$ is

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thank you for the response! Sorry, are you saying that any set with a single element from $X$ is both a chain and an antichain of $P$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For a poset with ground set $P$, isn't every set containing a single element of $X$ a chain of $P$?

Yes. Your reasoning is correct.

> $1$ is comparable to itself, therefore every pair of distinct elements in $\{1\}$ are comparable to each other

A minor nitpick here: $1$ is not distinct from itself. So you don't need to say that $1$ is comparable to itself to say that every pair of distinct elements is comparable. In fact, there are no pairs of distinct elements in $\{1\}$, and therefore "vacuously", every pair of distinct elements is comparable.

> But apparently $\{3\}$ is not a chain, but instead is an antichain of $P$. Why is this?

It is both a chain and an antichain!
In general, a set of elements in a Poset can be a chain, an antichain, neither, or both.

Comment: I see! This makes complete sense now, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

All singleton subsets of a poset are vacuously both chains and antichains.

Comment: +1. Elaborating for the OP: the definitions of both chain-ness and antichain-ness have the form "For every pair of distinct elements in the set, [stuff]." Remember that universal quantifications over the emptyset are vacuously true; the point now is that if $C$ is a one-element set, then the set of pairs of distinct elements of $C$ is the thing we're quantifying over, and that set is empty.

Comment: I see that now, thank you!

Comment: @NoahSchweber That's a helpful way of explaning this, I think I understand now, thank you!